# Angular - redirect to same component with different parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

So in angular I've nested routing, lets say:

```
domain.com/dashboard/list/:listId/:listName/details/:detailsName/:detailsId
```

- Dashboard is separate module
- List is separate module
- Details is separate module

Now, on `details` page, I've also small component with similar to list that I've on `list` page, and thats way I want also redirect user to the same `details` component but with different parameters.

So let's from :

```
domain.com/dashboard/list/1/test_list_name/details/test_details_name/4
```

to

```
domain.com/dashboard/list/1/test_list_name/details/another_test_details_name/8
```

**RouterLink:**

```
<h5 [routerLink]="['details', id, name]"></h5>
```

Unfortunately I'm always redirected to `/dashboard`. I tried it also with setting `routeReuseStrategy` to `false`. But without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

**@Edit, stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8fasa

In stackblitz example I just want to open another dashboard-second component(with different parameters) from dashboard-second component. In this example I've used only one nested routing, but issues is exactly same.

Sorry for quite ugly example, but I believe you will understand my problem.

Comment: Can you include your appcomponent and routes you've configured?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: Use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })` and look at what is in the console. I suspect it's trying to access `details/details` and you might have to change your router link to `<h5 [routerLink]="['../details', id, name]"></h5>`

Comment: It looks like you are passing the id before the name, but your route is declared as having the name, then the id

Comment: Name and Id are ok, i just made issue here on SO. I will try provide stackblitz asap.

Comment: @TomTom, Why not subscribe to route.paramMap https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service ?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Stackblitz attached in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })`, I see the following in the console:

`Event: NavigationEnd
    NavigationEnd(id: 3, url: '/dashboard/dashboard-second/original-name-something-bla-bla/87/dashboard-second/other-name/11', urlAfterRedirects: '/dashboard')
    NavigationEnd {id: 3, url: "/dashboard/dashboard-second/original-name-something-bla-bla/87/dashboard-second/other-name/11", urlAfterRedirects: "/dashboard"}`

So it has `dashboard-second` twice.

I had to change the routerlinks to:

```
<h5 [routerLink]="['../../../../dashboard-second', 'other-name', 11]" >Go to dashboard-second 1</h5>
```

It fixes the problem. The 4 .. is to go back to `/dashboard`. Each `..` go to:

1. 87 (ie: /87/.. = /87)
2. original-name-something-bla-bla
3. dashboard-second
4. /dashboard

It's a bit unintuitive that it takes 4 `..`, I thought it would have taken 3, but it makes sense because it's relative. So you end up doing:

`/dashboard/dashboard-second/original-name-something-bla-bla/87/../../../../dashboard-second/other-name/11`

which resolves to:

`/dashboard/dashboard-second/other-name/11`

You can also set an absolute path, with the caveat that if you move the route /dashboard-second around, it is more likely you have to update the routerLink when using absolute paths:

```
<h5 [routerLink]="['/dashboard/dashboard-second', 'name-name-name', 13]" >Go to dashboard-second 3</h5>
```

Comment: So now the ULR change properly, but the component is not reloaded. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Ok, about that reloading it was my mistake actually. Anyway thanks for your anserw, I've marked it as correct one. :)

Comment: Np! if you want to reload a dashboard when someone clicks on a link pointing to the same dashboard, you might want to set `onSameUrlNavigation` to `reload` inside `RouterModule.forRoot`. Otherwise clicking the link won't do anything (which might be completely fine, just depends on what you want to do)